# Treating a to-many as a to-one due to a "lookup" table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If I have a (hugely simplified) table like this:

`pages`:

```
id [PK]
version_id [PK]
name
```

Then I could create a relationship to it like this from another entity:

```php
class SomeEntity
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Page::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'page_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'page_version_id', referencedColumnName: 'version_id')]
    private ?Page $page = null;

    public function getPage(): ?Page
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}
```

(p.s. the keys are generated string sequences, not auto increments or UUIDs)

But let's say that I didn't have the 'version_id' when storing the relationship to it - let's say that it was in a table called `component_versions`, which is shared by not just pages, but a bunch of other things too (pointing that out, else it'd just be easy enough to create a proper relationship from here on - but it's dynamic):

```
component_id
latest_version_id
```

Can I still achieve the same thing? So when I do `$whatever->getPage()` it always returns me the latest version? I got close with this, but it's not pretty:

```php
class SomeEntity
{
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'component_versions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'component_id', referencedColumnName: 'page_id')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'component_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'latest_version_id', referencedColumnName: 'version_id', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Page::class)]
    private ?ArrayCollection $pages = null;

    public function getPage(): ?Page
    {
        return $this->pages && ($page = $this->pages->first()) ? $page : null;
    }
}
```

But now I have an `ArrayCollection` rather than just a simple entity. Sure, my `getPage` and `setPage` methods can take care of the rest, but the above feels....not nice.

I'm not working with a DB schema that I have much control over, unfortunately. Are there any cleaner options here?

SQL I guess might be along the lines of this, if I was trying to get the page associated with `page_id` from my `sometable`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages p
JOIN component_versions cv
    ON p.id = cv.component_id
    AND p.version_id = cv.latest_version_id
JOIN sometable
    ON sometable.page_id = p.id
```

and because i've got a unique relationship here, I'm assured to get just the one I'm after.

Any pointers would be great!
Cheers